# Cannot Unzip a .tar.gz file

Tags: 18.04, apache2, tar, curl, tomcat

So, I am trying to install apache tomcat, upon me trying to unzip the tar file i am getting this error.

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I am trying to unzip it using the following command:
`tar xf apache-tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz`

I downloaded the file using this curl command:

````
curl -O http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.10/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz```
````

Comment: Try `tar xvfz apache-tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz`. The `z` indicates _gzip_ format.

Comment: "not is gzip format" is a very good clue pointing toward your next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that your gz file is probably just a html page:

```
>cat apache-tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz
><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
><html><head>
><title>404 Not Found</title>
></head><body>
><h1>Not Found</h1>
><p>The requested URL /pub/software/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.10/bin/apache->tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz was not found on this server.</p>
><hr>
><address>Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) Server at mirror.cc.columbia.edu Port 80</address>
></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URL is incorrect. Try:

```
curl -O http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz
```

or some other mirror for version 9.0.10